# Scheduled task to zip and copy folders

Tags: windows

How could I write a script in windows that starts every night at 2am, scans a directory for folders which were created the day before, puts them in a single .zip file (using 7zip) and moves this file to another location? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

One option is the task scheduling API in Windows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx